# How does express controller still work without binding the methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

In my typescript express app. I have a controller and router setup as shown

```
// TestController.ts
export class TestContoller {
    async create(req: express.Request, res. express.Response) {
        res.json({
            status: 'ok',
        });
    }
}
```

```
// router.ts
import express from 'express';
import { TestContoller } from './TestContoller';

const router = express.Router();
const testController = new TestController();

router.post('/', testController.create);

export default router
```

I am supposed to use

```
router.post('/', testController.create.bind(testController))
```

or add this to the constructor of the controller

```
this.create = this.create.bind(this)
```

but my router still works without doing either. Why is this possible?

Comment: `create` isn’t using `this`, so it’s really irrelevant…

Comment: the router accepts a function as a middleware so basically you neednt bind the function to any route per se

Comment: @deceze You are right. Tested with a controller using `this` in the method and it failed